# How do I get the contents of the second or third set of brackets with only Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

If I have a string like this:

Report - No Adj - Direct Deposit (1) (64402117-acdd-44f9-a9de-53a5b83b961a) (2014-08-20).dotx

I can get the contents of the first set of brackets using:

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

I'm using a third party program which only lets me pass in a RegEx string.

What Regular Expression would give me the contents of the second and third sets of brackets?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: It's a third party program that lets me pass in regex string.

Comment: Have you tried using a lookahead to make sure it's the last set of parantheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only the contents of the third set of brackets, you can use the following regex:

```
(?:\([^()]+\).*?){2}\(([^()]+)\)
```

Explanation:

```
(?:         # Begin group
  \(        #   Match '('
  [^()]+    #   Match any character that is not a '(' or ')'
  \)        #   Match ')'
  .*?       #   Content outside the brackets (until the next '(')
){2}        # Repeat the group exactly 2 times
\(          # Match '('
(           # Begin first capturing group
  [^()]+    #   Match any character that is not a '(' or ')'
)           # End first capturing group
\)          # Match ')'
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wT3kF3/1)

Comment: I feel like this is the easiest because I can use my first expression for the first set of brackest and then use this for the second and third sets adjusting the number in the braces { }.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is make your RegEx expression global `g` like:

http://regex101.com/r/rR8rR5/1

Comment: OP has stated that it's a third-party program they're using, not an actual programming language.

Comment: That third party program may have a 'global' checkbox